# Add default Backgrounds

Tags: theme-development, images

Is there code or a plugin that would make it possible to add default backgrounds, like you can with default headers in Twenty ten. Seems like the same frame work for backgrounds and headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no default way to do that yet, though there is a [Trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18623). I found this (untested) that may work for you: http://www.devblog.fr/2011/05/16/plusieurs-fonds-personnalises-wordpress-add_custom_background/

It's also worth noting the 3.4's [new way of defining a default background](http://make.wordpress.org/themes/2012/04/06/updating-custom-backgrounds-and-custom-headers-for-wordpress-3-4/) (still just one, though).

## Edit

Here's the code:

```
<?php
function wpse48332_setup_theme() {
    // Add support for custom backgrounds
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
        // Background color default
        'default-color' => '000',
        // Background image default
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/background.jpg'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse48332_setup_theme' );
?>
```

(Note that you can also define front end, admin, and preview style callbacks, as well.)

Comment: I was not very excited about the new updates in 3.4 until now. - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can, add this snippet to your theme `functions.php` file, if you're using version under WP 3.4:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_custom_background' );
```

Or if you have setup function for your theme, just add this call to it:

```
add_custom_background();
```

After you added it, new menu item "Background" will appear in your admin panel. At this page you can select custom background image or set background color:

[image: custom background menu page]

Comment: It seems that the `add_custom_background()` function is [deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_background)

Comment: @LeaCohen It will be deprecated in WP 3.4, but it is not in previous versions! As WP 3.4 is not released yet I can consider `add_custom_background` as appropriate function for adding custom background facilities.